# enqueue function in linked list

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm trying to understand the function "enqueue" my professor did but i don't get some steps.

```
struct queue_node {
int item;
struct queue_node* next;
};
typedef struct queue_node* queue;


int enqueue (queue* tail, int i) {
queue n;
queue *iter;
n = (queue)malloc(sizeof(struct queue_node));
if (!n) return 1;
n->item = i;
n->next = NULL;
for (iter=tail; *iter != NULL; iter = &((*iter)->next)
;
*iter = n;
return 0;
}
```

First of all that "typedef struct queue_node* queue;" is confusing me so i tried to reinterpret the code this way (please correct the code if i'm wrong)

```
struct queue_node {
int item;
struct queue_node* next;
};
typedef struct queue_node queue;

int enqueue (queue **tail, int i) {
queue *n;
queue **iter;
n = (queue)malloc(sizeof(struct queue_node));
if (!n) return 1; --->what does that mean?
n->item = i;
n->next = NULL;
for (iter=tail; **iter != NULL; iter = &((*iter)->next)--->last part of the for is unclear to me... can i rewrite it as "iter = **((iter)->next)"?
;
*iter = n; -->this is the part i don't really get...
return 0;
}
```

So by the way before trying to read the solution of my professor i tried to do an "enqueue" function on my own

```
typedef struct node{
int value;
struct node *next;
}node;

void enqueue(node *head,int data){
if(head->next != NULL){
enqueue(head->next,data);
}
node *new=NULL;
new=malloc(sizeof(node));
new->value=data;
new->next=NULL;
head->next=new;
}
```

Is this good? or i can't use it? Thank you all in advance for the help

Comment: Just remove the typedef completely, add a few struct keywords, and you'll be happy for the rest of your life.

Comment: It looks like there's something missing in the professor's last for loop, i was expecting another `)`

Comment: For C this does not matter but if you're using C++ you can not use `new` as a name for variables. It is a keyword for allocation

Comment: I concur with wilplasser. The biggest disservice your professor's code is giving you is the hiding of a pointer type `struct queue_node*` in a typedef alias `queue`. Stripping that and simplifying, [the **code** is *much* easier to follow](http://ideone.com/bX9PGL). There are only a couple of places where [hiding pointer types in typedefs can be beneficial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers), and your professor's code can easily be seen as *none* of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `typedef struct queue_node* queue;`defines a new type so that you can write

```
queue* myqueue = (queue*)malloc(sizeof(struct queue_node));
```

instead of

```
struct queue_node** myqueue = (struct queue_node**)malloc(sizeof(struct queue_node));
```

As pointed out in the comment this is a pointer-to-pointer type.

The line

```
if (!n) return 1;
```

tests if the pointer `n` is valid (i.e. not `NULL`) and returns 1 as an error code if the comparison fails.

Now the code

```
for (iter=tail; **iter != NULL; iter = &((*iter)->next)
{
    *iter = n; /* -->this is the part i don't really get... */
    return 0;
}
```

iterates over the list until you encounter a `NULL` pointer.
The line  `*iter = n;` dereferences the current iterator (in this case a pointer to the current `node` and assigns `n` to it. So this essentially searches for the end of the queue and assigns the the new element to the end.

```
**((iter)->next)
```

is not the same as

```
&((*iter)->next)
```

the statement `(*iter)->next`  dereferences `iter` which is a pointer to a pointer to a `struct queue_node` so that you only have the actual pointer to `queue`. Then it gets the `next` field from the `queue`. The `&` gives you a pointer to the element that is referenced by `next` (it is the address operator), whereas your code will give you the actual object that is referenced by `->next`.

Now for you're code:

```
void enqueue(node *head,int data)
{
    if(head->next != NULL) /* what happens if head is  NULL ?*/
    {
         enqueue(head->next,data);
    }
    node *new=NULL;
    new=malloc(sizeof(node));
    new->value=data;
    new->next=NULL;
    head->next=new;
}
```

Other than my comment at the beginning I can't see anything wrong with it. But I have not actually tested if the code runs ;)

I hope that makes things clearer. :) If there are any ambiguities with my explanation, please comment and do not simply downvote, I know I am not the most experienced `C` programmer.

Answer (score 2):

If to use your definition of the `queue`

```
struct queue_node 
{
    int item;
    struct queue_node *next;
};

typedef struct queue_node queue;
```

then the function will look the following way.

```
int enqueue( queue **tail, int item ) 
{
    queue *node = ( queue * )malloc( sizeof( queue ) );
    int success = node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        node->item = item;
        node->next = NULL;

        while ( *tail != NULL ) tail = &( *tail )->next;

        *tail = node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

Opposite to your function definition this function returns 1 in case of the success that is when the new node that will be appended to the queue is allocated successfully and 0 otherwise.

So if you declared a queue the following way

queue *head = NULL;

then a function call can look like

```
enqueue( &head, value );
```

where `value` is some integer expression.

As you see you need to pass the head of the `queue` indirectly using pointers. Otherwise if not to use pointers and to pass the head directly to the function then the function gets a copy of the head. So any changes of the copy in the function will not influence on the original head.

In this statement

```
    queue *node = ( queue * )malloc( sizeof( queue ) );
```

a new node is created. The function `malloc` returns pointer to the allocated dynamically node.

In this statement

```
    int success = node != NULL;
```

there is assigned the result of the expression  `node != NULL` (either 1 or 0) depending on whether the call of `malloc` was successful or not.

If the call of `malloc` was successful that is `node` is not equal to `NULL` then the new node is initialized and it is appended to the end of the queue.
        if ( success )
        {
            node->item = item;
            node->next = NULL;

```
        while ( *tail != NULL ) tail = &( *tail )->next;

        *tail = node;
    }
```

How to find the tail of the list?

If the list initially was empty then `*tail` is equal to `NULL` and the condition on the while `*tail != NULL` will be equal to false. So the current value of the `tail` that is equal to `NULL` is substituted for the address of the allocated node

```
*tail = node;
```

Otherwise if `*tail` is not equal to `NULL` we gets the data field `next` of the current node

```
( *tail )->next
```

and in turn take its address the same way as we passed the head to the function by reference

```
&( *tail )->next
```

AT last when this data field contains NULL we substitute this `NULL` for the address of the new created node.

if you want to write a recursive function that appends a new node to the queue then it can look like

```
typedef struct node
{
    int value;
    struct node *next;
} node;

void enqueue( node **tail, int data )
{
    if ( *tail != NULL )
    { 
        enqueue( &( *tail )->next, data );
    }
    else
    {
        node *tmp = malloc( sizeof( node ) );
        tmp->value = data;
        tmp->next = NULL;

        *tail = tmp;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You and your professor are basically treating the variables differently. Based on then naming I think the professor is aiming for a picture that looks kind of like this:
[image]

The `tail` pointer refers to that rightmost node you would dequeue from, and to get to the location that you enqueue, you iterate until you reach the front of the queue. Now the important thing to note here is that `iter` does not point directly to nodes, it points to the `next` cells within each node until it finds an `NULL` one, as I try to illustrate here.

[image]

I think in practice you are right with not wanting to loop through the queue just to add a node. Actual queue implementations (which are sometimes made using linked lists) want constant time `O(1)` enqueues and dequeues, so they hold on to a pointer to either end of the queue at all times.

On a final note, everyone has different opinions about C naming conventions, but I tend to agree with you that the professor's example had some confusing typedefs. Some code bases like the linux kernel recommend to not use typedefs at all for pointers or even structs.

Comment: Nice answer, but you need a gimp tutorial :P

Comment: @AlterMann i would never betray ms paint